# Nested for loop in Django Template not able to loop through a dictionary item

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Part of a small ecommerce project I'm trying to build.

The **views.py** function that displays the order_info

```
@login_required
def past_orders_view(request):
    print (request.user)
    allOrders = Order.objects.filter(full_name=request.user)
    return render(request, "orders.html", {'Orders':allOrders})
```

The *allOrders* queryset from db looks like, which will display the orders for the particular logged in user:

```
<QuerySet[<Order: 13-{'Zenbook 14': '82990.00', 'iPhone 11 64gb': '61999.00'}-godric-+919871199215>]>
```

In template, I have something like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <head>
   <tr>
     <th> Ordered Date </th>
     <th> Status </th>
     <th> Product Name </th>
     <th> Price </th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
{% for order in Orders %}
   <tr>
    <td> {{order.date}} </td>
    <td> {{order.status}} </td>
    <td> {{ order.items_json }} </td>
    <td> {{ order.items_json }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Also, in view.py the model object for Order saves these info when placing an order

```
order = Order(items_json=items_json, full_name=name, town_or_city=city,                  
              phone_number=phone, status=status, date=timezone.now())
order.save()
```

So, the **Order** objects such as ***full_name, status, date*** can be directly accessed through a for loop in the template, and displayed as desired in the HTML. The problematic part is looping through the dictionary which has product name as key, and it's price as the value.
Already tried nested for loops, couldn't get the answer.

Tried loop sample:

```
{% for order in Orders %}
   <tr>
    {% for key,value in order.items_json.items %}
       <tr>
        <td> {{order.date}} </td>
        <td> {{order.status}} </td>
        <td> {{ key}} </td>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
      </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Help needed!!!

Comment: What is actually appearing in the rendered HTML?  Is there any info in the server console?

Comment: When I try the loop sample (last portion of the question above), it fails to display anything. Although when I display **order.items_json**, while iterating over _Orders via a single for-loop_, this displays **{'Zenbook 14': '82990.00', 'iPhone 11 64gb': '61999.00'}**

Comment: I suspect that `order.items_json` is actually a string not a dictionary.  I would look at converting it to a dictionary in your Python code (possibly looping through `orders` and assigning a new property in the order with a true dictionary.

Comment: Yep! You were right. Checked the type of it in the view.py and found out it to be a string with dictionary inside. Worked it out with the help of regex on the _orders_ and then using _eval_ to convert it back into a dictionary. Thanks for pointing it out! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or simply make this part of your view and pass it along the context

If you want reuse this in multiple locations you can create a simple custom template tag as provided [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Example for your case:

```py
class tuple_to_object:
  def __init__(self, input_tuple):
    self.key = input_tuple[0]
    self.value = input_tuple[1]

def get_key_values(dictionary):
  l = list(dictionary.items())
  return [tuple_to_object(item) for item in l]

...
orders = get_key_values(User.order_set.all()
render(request, 'path/to/view.html', {"orders":orders)})
```

And in your views:

```html
{% for order in orders %}
  {{order.key}}
  {{order.value}}
{% endfor %}
```

**Note**: This isn't tailor fit to your question but the method is the same